# Contour labels are too close to the figure boundary

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour

I'm making a contour plot using `matplotlib`, and the labels generated by `clabel` are too close to the figure boundary.[image: close to the boundary] How can I make them better located? I tried the `manual` arg but since I have multiple contours from a for loop it is not easy to determine where to put each time beforehand. The code I used to plot is

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Test contours
"""
# %%
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


g = 9.8
rhoh = 929  # hydrate density
rhol = 1029  # seawater density
rhos = 2650  # dry sediment density
psi = 25  # constant friction angle °
H = 137.95  # min depth of the hydrate layer m
D = 17.6  # max thickness of the hydrate layer m
nu = [0.15, 0.45]  # min and max Poisson's ratio

# ----- Constants ----- #


def weight(phi=0.483):
    gammas = rhos * g  # unit weight of dry soil
    gammal = rhol * g  # unit weight of seawater

    return gammal, (gammas - gammal) * (1 - phi)


# ----- Critical stress ----- #


def normal(H, beta):
    beta = np.deg2rad(beta)
    _, gammap = weight()
    return H * gammap * np.cos(beta) ** 2


def slip(H, beta, nu, E):
    sigma0 = normal(H, beta)
    G = E / 2 / (1 + nu)
    df = np.tan(np.deg2rad(psi))
    du_slip = sigma0 - 0.579 * G / 100 / df / (1 - nu)
    du_slip[du_slip < 0] = np.nan
    return du_slip


def mesh(N):
    Hd = H + np.linspace(0, D, N)
    nuu = np.linspace(nu[0], nu[1], N)
    Hd, nnuu = np.meshgrid(Hd, nuu)
    return Hd, nnuu


E = 70e6
beta = [5, 10, 15]

N = 1000
Hd, nu = mesh(N)

du_slip = []
for i in range(len(beta)):
    du_slip.append(slip(Hd, beta[i], nu, E))

styles = ["-", "--", ":", "-."]
colors = ["k", "b", "r", "g"]

levels = np.arange(0.5, 0.9, 0.1)
for i in range(len(beta)):
    c = plt.contour(
        Hd - H,
        nu,
        du_slip[i] / 1e6,
        levels,
        colors=colors[i],
        linestyles=styles[i],
        linewidths=1,
    )
    # my current hack
    cl = plt.clabel(c, levels, fontsize=8, use_clabeltext=True)
    # for l in cl:
    #     # move the location of the label to avoid overlapping
    #     l.set_position(
    #         (
    #             l.get_position()[0] - 1,
    #             l.get_position()[1]
    #             - 0.005
    #             * np.tan(l.get_rotation() * np.pi / 180),  # 0.005 from trial and error
    #         )
    #     )
    plt.plot([], [], styles[i], color="k", label=rf"$\beta$={beta[i]}°")
plt.legend(loc="lower left", frameon=True)
plt.xlabel(r"$D$ (m)", fontsize=12)
plt.ylabel(r"$\nu$", rotation="horizontal", fontsize=12, labelpad=15)
plt.title(r"$\Delta u_\mathrm{slip}$ (MPa)", fontsize=12)

plt.savefig("test1.png", bbox_inches="tight")

# %%
```

My current hack is to get the locations and orientations of each label and move them down along the line a little bit

```
cl = plt.clabel(c, levels, inline=False, fontsize=8, use_clabeltext=True)
    for l in cl:
        # move the location of the label to avoid overlapping
        l.set_position(
            (
                l.get_position()[0] - 1,
                l.get_position()[1]
                - 0.005
                * np.tan(l.get_rotation() * np.pi / 180),  # 0.005 from trial and error
            )
        )
```

and the plot becomes[image: better but...] Better but still not good enough.

Answer (score 1):

`clabel` allows for manual location of labels. Simply replace your hack with

```
plt.clabel(c, inline=True, fmt="%1.1f", fontsize=10, manual=True)
```

(I added personal formatting styling for reference).

Running the script will open a window with your plot and you will be prompted to left-click (one tap on touchpad) on the location where you want each label. Then when you are happy with the locations you can continue to the next iteration of contours with with a right-click (three-finger tap on touchpad). Repeat until all contours are labeled, then a final right-click to close the prompt. Your image should be saved locally as normal with the labels on it.

[image]`

Comment: Yes I tried this. This works if I have only a few sets of contour, but is there a more automatic way?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I myself had to deal with this long ago, and even posted an issue on the matplotlib github. This is the best we have.